# 500 Internal Server Error Causes

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

My site is up for a long time (signup page closed), but when opening the signup page and I think many visitor is trying to access the said page. Now it cause a problem, a `Internal Server Error` here it is:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@sample.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When trying to refresh the site, error sometime disappears and sometime be back again. I have [searched](https://www.besthostinganddesign.com/500-internal-server-error/) what causes of this, and tried to remove my `.htaccess` file. When tried to visit the website homepage and refresh it many times, error disappears! So, methinks that it can be the cause of the server error.

This is the content of my htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

What is wrong with the configuration. And what other can cause this error?

Additional: If we got high traffic about 1k+ users at a time, we got this error but when we only got 500 users below error is not showing.

Comment: check your logs

Comment: conditions before the rules and the 2 rules dont make sense being almost identical and the L one

Comment: There's no error listed on the log that the problem occurred(date)

Comment: @rtfm rules, What should it be?

Comment: try delete\disable rule 1 then leave the conditions and last rule alone

Comment: I have tried that error is file not found, I have a code doing a parse/trim the url page for the page to view.

Comment: i would admit to mod rewrite not being my special area of knowledge and hope some one else can help

Answer (score 0):

i think header module is disbled
try On your command line:

first of `Install mod_headers`

`sudo a2enmod headers` and then restart apache

service apache2 restart